# Pass looping foreach variable using post

Tags: php, html

My code is here https://eval.in/740034

It consists of a foreach that loops through, sets the name of the radio to the looping variable name, and tries to post it to the next page.

How do i distinguish between different radio buttons being selected and pass them onto the next page.

Answer (score 1):

When you send a post request, the data sent in the request are indexed by the "name" attribute put onto the radio buttons. Simply check the value of $_POST["whatever_the_radio_name_is_here"] and/or see if it isset, depending on how you have the values setup, this would be something you'd check for in your addtocart.php file.

Comment: Okay so I do the loop. and the radios get set up like 

`<input type='radio' name='$name' value='big'/>`(where $name = foo) 

`<input type='radio' name='$name' value='big'/>` (where $name = bar) 

What would I put in my addtocart.php as the `$foo = $_POST[$name]`?

Comment: Or should I leave the `name` as static and be setting the `value='$name'`?

Comment: You'd want the values to be something different, otherwise they'll both just be a radio for "big". You'd also want the `$name` variable to be different for both. Essentially, you have two radio buttons that are exactly the same, so when you send the POST data, it'll just collapse to one value. I'd recommend doing this:

    <input type='radio' name='". $name1 . "' value='big'/>
    <input type='radio' name='". $name2 . "' value='small'/>

That way in the POST data, you can tell the difference.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're using to set your $name variable, but if it's the same each time, make the two different static names and set the value dynamically if that's the only part you're changing. If you set the name dynamically, it'll be harder to search for it from the $_POST variable in addtocart.php.

Comment: The $name var is just looping through a file and displaying pictures and setting them as radio buttons. I have like 15 `$names` so I'd prefer to not have a static name. Is it possible to search for dynamic names from the next page?

Comment: In that case, if the `$counter` correlates at all to the `$name` variable, do something like `<input type='radio' name='". $name . $counter . "' value='big'/>`. Then in the next page you can run a foreach loop over $_POST and do a regex check over the keys for something ending with a number (the value of the counter). The rest of your name values don't end in numbers, so this will let you know which one is the name variable without it being static. e.g. if `$name` is "example" and `$counter` is 0, then the name value will be "example0".